# SQL Server Update Statement Execution

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to update only 2 rows from top.

Here I am using update statement like

```
UPDATE orderDetails 
SET status = 56 
WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT TOP 2 orderID   
                  FROM orderDetails 
                  WHERE station = 701)
```

But it is updating all rows, not considering 'TOP 2' in select statement.

Comment: `TOP 2` *order by* what?? If you use `TOP`, you **must** specify an `ORDER BY` - otherwise, you just get an arbitrary 2 rows ....

Comment: I have only 4 rows for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your query using **order by** clause:

```
UPDATE orderDetails 
SET status = 56 
WHERE OrderID IN 
(
   SELECT TOP 2 orderID   
   FROM orderDetails WHERE station = 701
   ORDER BY <COLNAME> DESC   -- You need to decide what column you want to sort on
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
update top (2) orderDetails 
SET status=56 
WHERE ORDErID in (select orderID   FROM orderDetails WHERE station=701)
```

Or you can try like this:

```
;with cte as
( 
select top 2 * 
from orderDetails 
WHERE station = 701
order by somecolumn    --You need to specify the column on which you will make order by
) 
update cte set status=56
```